# How can I use execl() inside fork() and kill it

Tags: c++, c, linux, fork

I need to execute a binary file using C and terminate it using kill, But the process is not get started using execl() inside fork. I am using the following code,

```
pid_t PID = fork();
 if(PID == 0) {
     execl("/home/pi/mjpg-streamer/mjpg_streamer -i \"/home/pi/mjpg-streamer/input_uvc.so -n -f 15 -r 640x480\" -o \"/home/pi/mjpg-streamer/output_http.so -n -w /home/pi/mjpg-streamer/www \"",(char*)0);
      exit(1);
 }

// Wait to kill child process
int p;
cin>>p;
kill(PID, 15);  //Sends the SIGINT Signal to the process, telling it to stop.
```

Can any one help me to solve this...

Thanks....

Comment: In that case my information was incredibly wrong so I deleted my comments. I hope someone else can help you - sorry to put you on the wrong path.

Comment: Why are you using `cin>>p` and labeling your question `C`?  That looks like `C++`

Comment: Ok sorry for that I will edit my tags..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're passing a full command line to the `execl()` call, which is invalid.

The arguments to the call are 1) the path to the executable, 2...n) the command line components (the argv that main receives), and n+1) the 0 terminator. So for your need, the call should look something like:

```
execl("/home/pi/mjpg-streamer/mjpg_streamer", "mjpg_streamer", "-i", "/home/pi/mjpg-streamer/input_uvc.so -n -f 15 -r 640x480", "-o", "/home/pi/mjpg-streamer/output_http.so -n -w /home/pi/mjpg-streamer/www", (char*)0);
```

Place a `perror("execl:");` after the execl call... if your perror is reached, your parameters are still not what they need to be (because the call is still failing to execute a new process) and the error may help indicate the cause.

Comment: I guess you should not pass the double quotes in the argument list.  They are used to convince the shell not to split this up.  No shell involved here, so no double quotes.